# When should I create a new F5 LTM virtual server compared to using an existing one with a policy?

Tags: f5

I'm pretty new to F5 LTM and have inherited a setup from a former colleague. There are multiple virtual servers all listening on port 443 with SSL offloading. Some of them have a policy associated containing some rules like:

- If Host header equals site**A**.com forward traffic to pool_A
- If Host header equals site**B**.com forward traffic to pool_B
- If Host header equals sub.site**C**.com forward traffic to pool_C
- If Host header equals sub2.site**C**.com forward traffic to pool_D

Other virtual servers just use a default pool without any policies or irules.

Is it a good practice to keep adding sites to this policy? When would I use a separate virtual server, assuming that I can always use the same virtual server settings (HTTP profile, service port etc)?

I have the feeling that I would be able to combine all virtual servers into one virtual server with policies, so I don't see why I would each time use a new virtual server and take another IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluating those policies (I assume done with iRules) costs CPU resources for *every* HTTP request made to the load balancer. If you have some heavy traffic sites, this can affect the performance of the LTM quite a lot. Especially if the list of sites grows longer.

In my book, what your doing is a trick to make sure several websites use the virtual server and thus the same external IP address, even though they're handled differently in the backend. If possible, I'd use a virtual server for every pool you have, sometimes even a different virtual server for every site you host (especially when you need to use different SSL profiles). It reduces load and complexity.

Comment: The policies are made using LTM Policies, not iRules, but I suppose that doesn't make a big difference. Having a different VS for each site, would mean we need to have many public IPs as well, which are quite scarce.

Comment: I don't think that makes much of a difference. I understand that not everyone has a big pool of IPv4 addresses available for this. I'd consider trying to find a balance between the number of virtual servers you have and the amount of rules required. If you can combine sites that share properties into one virtual server, so you can at least reduce the number of rules somewhat.

Comment: LTM traffic policies ARE compiled and don't cost nearly the same amount of resources as iRules which require the VS to open the TCL handler to process the logic.  There's benefit either way. If you have enough unique needs for the traffic, a VS is the way to go. If it's traffic going to the same "application" but needs some logic within the routing LTM policy then iRule if it gets complicated.

There are some good articles to help determine which way to go: https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/ltm-policy-matching-strategies-20834

Comment: how you handle your traffic depends on a lot of factors, not just "can" you do it all in a virtual -vs- a policy -vs- an iRule. As Chase mentions, each has their benefits and concerns. If you have 100 applications that are very similar and can be handled in a single virtual server with light policy or iRule work, that reduction in object count is beneficial. But keep in mind that policies are compiled PER VIRTUAL, so even if you're using one policy, if it's large and you have a lot of virtuals, there is concern for daemon timeouts. Test, test, test...